# How can I make the "gn" motion wrap to the beginning of the file?

Tags: search

`gn` is a very useful command that selects the next search result. For example, if I insert

```
foo bar baz
```

into a file, move to the beginning, type `/[aeiou].`, and press `gn`, it would select `oo` in a visual selection. Pressing `dgn` would delete that and then select `ar` in a visual selection.

However, let's say I have the following file (where **`[x]`** represents the cursor):

```
This is some text.

Blah blah blah.

Lorem ipsum.

Foo bar b[a]z quux.
```

and I've searched for `. .` (any character, a space, then any character). Pressing `dgn` would delete the `z q`, since it's the first search result after my cursor. However, pressing `gn` from here now has no effect, since this motion does not "wrap around" back to the beginning of the file like `n` does.

How can I make `gn` wrap to the first search result if there are no results after the cursor (but still have no effect (or give an error, without moving the cursor) if there are no more results in the entire file), just like the `n` command?

---

After discussion in the comments: This may be system-specific. I'm running Vim 7.4.52 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Turns out `gn` wraps for me. Now I have to figure out what enables it. Ok - this wraps even with `-u NONE`.

Comment: @muru Weird... it still doesn't wrap with `-u NONE` for me. What platform/version? I'm on Vim 7.4.52 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: 7.4 (included patches 1-580), Arch Linux. I'll test on a Ubuntu system. - Yep, doesn't wrap on Ubuntu.

Comment: @muru Hmm, interesting... I've edited another line into the question.

Comment: What about `ggdgn`? Or `:%s/. ./gc`?

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully there would be a better solution, but one solution is to upgrade.

For Ubuntu-based systems there's [a PPA](https://launchpad.net/~pi-rho/+archive/ubuntu/dev?field.series_filter=trusty) you can try (if you're unfamiliar with PPAs, see [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)). It currently has Vim 7.4.589, and `gn` wraps at least as of 7.4.580.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:pi-rho/dev
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vim
```

---

Looking at [the README](http://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/patches/7.4/README), I think the particular patch that introduced this was 76:

```
1894  7.4.076  "cgn" does not wrap around the end of the file
```

So if you're comfortable with recompiling vim to add a patch, this should be it.